# PrimeNG dropdown colored red after change

Tags: warnings, dropdown, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm using [PrimeNG's p-dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown).  The options are an array of labels and a value.  Every time after a change it is colored red at bottom.

Before selection, it looks like this:

[image: before select]

After selection, it looks like this:

[image: after selection]

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <span class="md-inputfield">
        <label class="floatPlaceHolder">{{schema.description | translate }}</label>
        <p-dropdown [disabled]="schema.readOnly==true?true:false" appendTo="body" [formControl]="control" [options]="schema.oneOf"
           [autoWidth]="false" appendTo="body" [filter]="schema.oneOf&&schema.oneOf.length>5"></p-dropdown >
    </span>
</div>
```

Typescript Code:

```
   "oneOf": [
            {
                "value": 0,
                "label": ""
            },
            {
                "value": 4,
                "label": "A"
            },
            {
                "value": 2,
                "label": "B"
            },
            {
                "value": 1,
                "label": "C"
            }
        ]
```

Comment: check you css classes/styles, do you have any red colors in there?

Comment: Do you have any `Validator` on that formControl? Usually primeNg uses that color to show invalid values on form items.